# Where do we specify in Eclipse the place to put the built classes?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am looking at the below location

```
/media/public_/workspaces/workspacemy/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/
```

there is nothing even after clean build.

Only after cleaning Tomcat a class comes.

I wonder if Eclipse build my classes and try to put some wrong place?

If so where can i configure that place.

Thanks.

Comment: i found out that my build by Eclipse MainPage->Project->Clean window->Start immediate build does not work. I do not know how to overcome.

Comment: i can "Project right click-> Build project" for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project name, click on properties. Select build path (in left pane), and then go to sources folder tab. At the bottom you can specify the default target location or you can specify target location for each source folder separately by clicking on each source folder.